# TypeError: children[x].firstChild is null

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, prototype

Converting prototype into jQuery -

Getting error

> TypeError: children[x].firstChild is null

How to convert `firstChild into jQuery`

```
this.drawNumbers = function() {
var children = this.getVisibleUsedElements();

for(var x=0;x<children.length;x++) {
  children[x].firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML = String(x + 1);

}
};
```

Comment: provide your html too. there should be other easy ways to do the stuff

Comment: what is the value of `children`

Comment: could you please tell me how to firstChild equivalent into jQuery?

Comment: `$('selector:first-child')`